# GeoXT .ssf files

Tags: rinex

I have changed the name of the project files when collecting data on a GeoXT collector.  When I use Pathfinder office to differentially correct the files, most of them cannot find the correct CORS base files from the NOAA website.  Is there a way to get the proper file name for the .ssf files so they will be corrected?

Answer (score 1):

From this [NOAA site](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/CORS/README.shtml) you should be able to find the correct site files
If you cannot get the site files for your collection times.
It is possible that the CORS Site was down during collection
(which can be checked prior to collection using planning software).
In that case you should select an alternate site as near as possible to the collection site.

[google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=&q=cors%20correction%20file%20download&oq=cors%20correction%20file%20download&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=112670l136028l0l156080l30l30l0l1l1l0l579l9072l2-15.13.0.1l29l0)
[download instructions Doc file](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEgQFjAD&url=http://www.nps.gov/gis/gps/gps4gis/how2s_byCatagories/6-GPSPostProcessing/GPS_Downloading_Field_Data_Denver_Office_Version_COStateParks.doc&ei=uMfRTunsMOSLsQK-zJntDg&usg=AFQjCNHV8cvh2cv_F629PESNfdcPKylM2A&sig2=mRsNVbMYhIBBCrvMgusxgg)